# IIS Express Windows Authentication

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-authentication, iis-express

I'm trying to use IIS Express with VS2010 to host a silverlight application.  I modified my applicationhost.config file to allow for modification of the proper configuration settings.  I have the following in my web.config:

```
<location path="">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I am not being authenticated and my domain service call returns a null record as the user.  I was able to get this to work after installing VS2010 SP1 BETA but I'm trying to get this to work with only IIS Express.

How do I enable Windows Authentication to work with IIS Express.  Is there a configuration setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

**option-1**:

edit `\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file and enable windowsAuthentication, i.e:

```
<system.webServer>
...
  <security>
...
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
...
  </security>
...
</system.webServer>
```

**option-2**:

Unlock windowsAuthentication section in \My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config as follows

```
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
```

Alter override settings for the required authentication types to 'Allow'

```
<sectionGroup name="security">
    ...
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        ...
        <sectionGroup name="authentication">
            <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            ...
            <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

Add following in the application's web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Below link may help:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/376/delegating-configuration-to-webconfig-files/

After installing VS 2010 SP1 applying option 1 + 2 may be required to get windows authentication working. In addition, you may need to set anonymous authentication to false in IIS Express applicationhost.config:

```
<authentication>

            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />
```

**for VS2015, the IIS Express applicationhost config file may be located here:**

```
$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

and the `<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>` option in the project file selects the default or solution-specific config file.

Comment: Thanks.  But I did try the options above.  But I'm still not able to use Windows Authentication.  I guess I will just have to wait for VS2010 / SP1 to get this functionality.

Comment: option two worked for me.  took a while to find this post though!

Comment: This question doesn't really apply anymore since VS2010 sp1 came out.  I was trying to get it to work without installing sp1.  My guess is that sp1 is doing something to set it up the first time that I just couldn't figure out.  I can go ahead and mark this answer correct, although it really isn't since sp1 not being installed was the pre-requisite.

Comment: Finally I found an answer that helped me solve a really strange IIS issue I was having: HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized! This was intermittent thingy. Sometimes it would work sometimes not... crazy thing. It started after a system reboot. Go figure...

Comment: Start > Run > "`%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`" directly opens the config file.

Comment: Thanks man! NTLM worked by disabling anonymous authentication.

Comment: Note that at least with VS 2014 when using Option 1, VS will copy those settings to all web projects once they are opened within VS.

Comment: Per this post, you need to use a 64-bit application (e.g. notepad) and not a 32-bit application (e.g. notepad++) to edit this file manually: http://www.cosnetics.co.uk/articles/cannot-manually-edit-applicationhost.config/

Comment: In VS2015 the IIS Express configuration moved into the solution structure, specifically, $(SolutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config sadly it does not take the existing configuration under MyDocuments\IISExpress into account so any customizations will need to be readded.

Comment: I did both and it finally worked (Visual Studio 2013), thanks!

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019 the applicationhost.config will be found in

DRIVE:\MYPROJECT\.vs\MYPROJECTNAME_FOLDER\config\applicationhost.config

Comment: This did not work for me, but the following answer by roryWoods did.

Answer (score 413):

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and 2012 added support for IIS Express eliminating the need to edit angle brackets.

1. If you haven't already, right-click a web-flavored project and select "Use IIS Express...".
2. Once complete, select the web project and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to focus the Properties panel.
3. Set the "Windows Authentication" property to Enabled, and the "Anonymous Authentication" property to Disabled.

[image]

I believe this solution is superior to the vikomall's options.

- Option #1 is a global change for all IIS Express sites.
- Option #2 leaves development cruft in the web.config.

  - Further, it will probably lead to an error when deployed to IIS 7.5 unless you follow the "unlock" procedure on your IIS server's applicationHost.config.

The UI-based solution above uses site-specific location elements in IIS Express's applicationHost.config leaving the app untouched.

More information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288080.aspx

Comment: To emphasize what I missed - the properties context menu and `Alt-Enter` shortcut don't completely supplant the properties pane details that allow you to change whether windows authentication is enabled or not. Use `F4` or click on the properties pane to actually see the properties.

Comment: I struggled with this task for several days before starting over with this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx  Basically, disregard everything in the original post, start over with a "virgin" applicationhost.config and just enable the settings as per this answer.  Finally I get Windows authentication!  Thanks!!

Comment: It ends up changing the the IISExpressWindowsAuthentication setting from 'enabled' to disabled' in the .csproj. <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>

Comment: Those 2 options are grayed out and disabled for me. Any idea why?

Comment: the 2 options are grayed out because you have this in your IIS Express Config 

<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow"/>

<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" /> 
take out the overrideModeDefault="Allow" and they will ungray out

Comment: this turned out to be a lifesaver. most of our apps are intranet apps so it's necessary to use windows authentication, and it always worked fine until we upgraded to vs2013.

Comment: Yes, upgrading from the Cassini engine (default) of vs 2010 to  vs 2013 (default of iis express and no more cassini )  I KNEW it was the Auth / pipeline but at first I kept trying to hack an application  :/  This solution works great!

Comment: It works for me. But first I can't change Windows Authentication property.When I run my app, I can change it.

Comment: My problem only solved after running Visual Studio as Admin.

Comment: applicable in VS2015 too. Thanks for this post:)

Comment: This still applies, works in VS2019. Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: I have both these options set and still get 401.1 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 10):

Building upon the answer from booij boy, check if you checked the "windows authentication" feature in 
Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn windows features on or of -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security

Also, there seems to be a big difference when using firefox or internet explorer. 
After enabeling the "windows authentication" it works for me but only in IE.

Comment: And getting it to work in firefox: http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/

Comment: here it is: https://web.archive.org/web/20080531061006/http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/

Answer (score 5):

In addition to these great answers, in the context of an IISExpress dev environment, and in order to thwart the infamous "system.web/identity@impersonate" error, you can simply ensure the following setting is in place in your applicationhost.config file.

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will allow you more flexibility during development and testing, though be sure you understand the implications of using this setting in a production environment before doing so.

Helpful Posts:

- http://forums.iis.net/post/1873372.aspx
- http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

Comment: Landed on this completely by accident, but it worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

In IIS Manager click on your site.
You need to be "in feature view" (rather than "content view")

In the IIS section of "feature view" choose the so-called feature "authentication"
and doulbe click it.
Here you can enable Windows Authentication.
This is also possible (by i think in one of the suggestions in the thread) by a setting in the web.config  (  ...)

But maybe you have a web.config you do not want to scrue too much around with.
Then this thread wouldnt be too much help, which is why i added this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help if: 1) your site used to work with Windows authentication before upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 and 2) and your site is attempting to load `/login.aspx` (even though there is no such file on your site).

Add the following two lines to the `appSettings`section of your site's `Web.config`.

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### On the same note - VS 2015, .vs\config\applicationhost.config not visible or not available.

By default .vs folder is hidden (at least in my case).

If you are not able to find the .vs folder, follow the below steps.

1. Right click on the Solution folder
2. select 'Properties'
3. In `Attributes` section, click `Hidden` check box(default unchecked),
4. then click the 'Apply' button
5. It will show up confirmation window 'Apply changes to this folder, subfolder and files' option selected, hit 'Ok'.

   Repeat step 1 to 5, except on `step 3`,    this time you need to `uncheck` the 'Hidden' option that you checked previously.

Now should be able to see .vs folder.

Answer (score 0):

After doing everything in the above answers, I figured out I was not running Visual Studio as Admin. After running as Admin, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers helps, you might need to adjust the project properties. Check this other StackOverflow answer on how to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857049/56621

Answer (score 0):

I'm using visual studio 2019 develop against ASP.Net application. Here's what been worked for us:

1. Open your Project Property Windows, Disable **Anonymous Authentication** and Enable **Windows Authentication**
2. In your **Web.Config** under **system.web**

```html
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

And I didn't change application.config in iis express.