# IIS Express HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-authentication, iis-express

I have tried the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication) but I can not get Windows Authentication working with IIS Express in Vision Studio 2010. Now I get following error:
[image: 401.2 Error]

Here are my applicationhost.config file entries:

```
...
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
...
<authentication>

    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />

    <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />

    <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />

    <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />

    <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
    </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>

    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
</authentication>
...
<sectionGroup name="authentication">
    <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="digestAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
```

My web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />        
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This is .NET 4

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure you have something like below in your applicationhost.config file

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add value="Negotiate" />
    <add value="NTLM" />
   </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

This file is probably in `%HOMEPATH%\Documents\IISExpress\config\`

Comment: This fixed by issue, It is about line number 388. default is "false"

Comment: Where is applicationhost.config for IIS express?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946476/where-is-the-iis-express-configuration-metabase-file-found

Comment: applicationhost.config file is probably inC:\Users\yourname\Documents\IISExpress\config

Comment: For .NET Core, the `applicationhost.config` file is in the .vs folder in your solution directory.

Answer (score 7):

I've had such a problem in VS 2013 with IIS 8.0 Express when I wanted to update Service Reference. A dialog popped up asking for username/password. A strange substring was added to the service url:

```
_vti_bin/ListData.svc
```

I started configuring windows authentization as mentioned in some posts in this page in applicationhost.config. Finally, the working configuration can't have Negotiate provider:

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <!--<add value="Negotiate" />-->
    <add value="NTLM" />
   </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

And the anonymous authentication must be disabled:

```
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Removing the Negotiate was the trigger! I have tried everything else that stackoverflow has mentioned for this general 401 issue. So the only fix that was needed was to set windowsAuthentication enabled=true and comment out "Negotiate". I have both anonymous and windows auth enabled in applicationHost.config and in Visual Studio properties on the web project.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```