# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is empty every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

It may be duplication question but I did not found any solution from other post.

I am using Windows authentication, when I am building application on local system its working fine but when I am deploying the application on IIS HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is returning null. I have disable eveything except Windows authentication on authentication setting.

```
var strUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == "" ? System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name : HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

I am getting strUserName null.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>

<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

I try to divide the line and write the code to check what is exactly returing...

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is returning null
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name is returning NT AUTHORITY\IUSR when impersonate is true
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name is returning IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationPoolName when impersonate is false
```

below few link I have checked

[HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is empty using IIS Express but not Visual Studio Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363766/httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-is-empty-using-iis-express-but-not-visual)

[User.Identity.Name with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276067/user-identity-name-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: I would like to recommend you to [edit] your question and add the other similar questions you have found and tried to avoid getting your question flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: I believe that second `<authentication>` tag overwrites the first one in above example so `mode=Windows` doesn't get picked up. Can you try merging both configuration items?

Comment: Are you referring to a service/WCF?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer - Click on the web application project -> At the bottom select the Properties tab.Make sure you have the following set:

1. Anonymous Authentication | **Disabled**
2. Windows Authentication | **Enabled**

Change your Web.config like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Now try accessing the current Windows user like this:

```
string user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: setting are same as you suggested, when I clean the browser history and make anonymous authentication as disable again, it started showing user name password window but it is not accepting the credentials and I am able to take remote with same credentials. It should not show any popup directly it has to check the user and redirect to default screen.

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Comment: when I am trying to add  <identity impersonate="false"/> then it is show IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationName and when I am making it true it is showing NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR, but it is not giving user name. I don't know do I need to using impersonate or not

Comment: You need to remove all the sign in forms from your application and any logic that redirects users to the login page.You should also have a home page called Default.aspx or configure IIS to serve another page by default if yours has a different name

Answer (score 0):

Try these setting in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.webServer> 
</system.webServer>
```