# How to run web service from Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: asp.net, web-services, silverlight, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

asmx web service used by silverlight application project was created in Visual Web Developer and converted
to Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25421.03 Update 3

For debugging application is run using IIS Express from IDE.
ITs running returns error

```
Unhandled Error in Test Application 
Code: 2104    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings
```

Typing http://localhost:1839/  to browser returs error in browser

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:

Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   Unknown 

Handler
   Not yet determined 

Error Code
   0x80070003 

Config Error
   Cannot read configuration file  

Config File
   \\?\C:\Users\andrus\Documents\My Web Sites\Web-Site\web.config
```

How to fix this ?

C:\Users\andrus\Documents\My Web Sites\Web-Site\web.config

C:\Users\andrus\Documents\My Web Sites\Web-Site directory does not exist.
It looks like IIS Express is not running.

web.csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{136BE0FD-EE89-4F44-87A9-2C3958CD4D28}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>Test.Service</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>Test.Service</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<!--<SilverlightApplicationList>{65869BFA-DC52-4F58-B153-C81BB864BE5B}|..\TestSL\TestSL.csproj|ClientBin|False</SilverlightApplicationList>-->
<FileUpgradeFlags>
</FileUpgradeFlags>
<UpgradeBackupLocation>
</UpgradeBackupLocation>
<OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
<!--<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>-->
<!--<IISExpressSSLPort />-->
<!--<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />-->
<TargetFrameworkProfile />
<!--<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />-->
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>
</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
<!--<ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>-->
<!--<ExcludeApp_Data>true</ExcludeApp_Data>-->
<AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
<RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
<!--<PublishDatabases>false</PublishDatabases>-->
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>http</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
<!--<ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>-->
<!--<PublishDatabases>false</PublishDatabases>-->
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.85.1.271, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
<HintPath>..\..\Test\Dependencies\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\packages\Npgsql.2.2.7\lib\net40\Mono.Security.dll</HintPath>
<Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Npgsql, Version=2.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\packages\Npgsql.2.2.7\lib\net40\Npgsql.dll</HintPath>
<Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.Linq">
<!--<RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>-->
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization">
<!--<RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>-->
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
<Reference Include="System.XML" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="ClientBin\TestSL.xap" />
<Content Include="login.htm" />
<Content Include="ClientBin\Toolbar\Paste_big.png" />
<Content Include="ClientBin\Toolbar\Print_big.png" />
<Content Include="Silverlight.js" />
<Content Include="StockService.asmx" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="GetStockStatus.ashx.cs">
<DependentUpon>GetStockStatus.ashx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="RefreshStockStatus.ashx.cs">
<DependentUpon>RefreshStockStatus.ashx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Eva.svc.cs">
<DependentUpon>Eva.svc</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\CartService.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\TestMenuItem.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\MenuBuilder.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\WholeMenuBuilder.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\StockService.cs">
<SubType>Component</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Service\TreeNodeData.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\UserCredentials.cs" />
<Compile Include="Report.ashx.cs">
<DependentUpon>Report.ashx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Service\WSDLDocumentationAttribute.cs" />
<Compile Include="Service\WSDLDocumentationImportExtension.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Service Include="{3259AA49-8AA1-44D3-9025-A0B520596A8C}" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Test\dblinq\DbLinq.PostgreSql\DbLinq.PostgreSql.csproj">
<Project>{32824F7E-9260-413C-B174-F3E315936FA7}</Project>
<Name>DbLinq.PostgreSql</Name>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Test\dblinq\DbLinq\DbLinq.csproj">
<Project>{97305421-3071-4175-AA3C-9A432CC28121}</Project>
<Name>DbLinq</Name>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Test\Test Business\Business.csproj">
<Project>{3A578D21-8E0C-4CB9-B22D-D4616DCE1E45}</Project>
<Name>Business</Name>
</ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="ShowReport.aspx" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Eva.svc" />
<Content Include="ReportViewer.js" />
<Content Include="XamlReport.aspx" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="favicon.ico" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedResource Include="ExcelTemplate.xml" />
<Content Include="index.htm" />
<Content Include="Report.ashx" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="GetStockStatus.ashx" />
<Content Include="RefreshStockStatus.ashx" />
<Content Include="packages.config" />
<None Include="web.config">
<SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\Profile1.pubxml" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<!--<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>-->
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
<!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
-->
<ProjectExtensions>
<VisualStudio>
<FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
<WebProjectProperties>
<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
<AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort>
<DevelopmentServerPort>1839</DevelopmentServerPort>
<DevelopmentServerVPath>/Test</DevelopmentServerVPath>
<IISUrl>http://localhost:1839/Test</IISUrl>
<NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
<UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
<CustomServerUrl>http://localhost</CustomServerUrl>
<SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
</WebProjectProperties>
</FlavorProperties>
</VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Posted also in http://forums.asp.net/p/2098544/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for applicationhost.config ([Where is the IIS Express configuration / metabase file found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946476/where-is-the-iis-express-configuration-metabase-file-found)) and check is the path for your application valid.