# IIS Express applicationhost.config - authentication error

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-core, iis-express

I'm running IIS Express (not to be confused with the normal IIS) under Windows 10. My understanding is the settings are stored in "My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config"

These settings can be overriden by a local web.config file when using creating an asp.net core project.

When attempting to use this web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <location path="" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>    
</configuration>
```

I receive the following error.

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

identifying this line

```
<authentication>
**<anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />**
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
```

This in spite of changing this line to state allow

```
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Is there any other place I should be looking?

Comment: Your first paragraph is a big mistake https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html

Answer (score 6):

Based upon feedback received.

The correct location for the configuration file is  {ProjectDirectory}.vs\config\applicationhost.config when working within visual studio.

"My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" is incorrect

Comment: For those looking, I think it's actually {solution folder}\.vs\{web project name}\config\applicationhost.config.

Comment: That is only true for some versions of VS... See the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946476/where-is-the-iis-express-configuration-metabase-file-found For VS 2015 & VS 2017: ... Right-click the IIS Express system tray icon (when running the application), and select "Show all applications":
Context menu for IIS Express system tray icon showing the alternative "Show all applications" highlighted
Then, select the relevant application and click the applicationhost.config file path: