# HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I hosted a .NET CORE 3.0(razor pages) application which was running fine after few days for no reason it was just displaying ***HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process  Common solutions to this issue:
Select a different application pool to create another in-process application.***, then I found this solution [HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246822/http-error-500-35-ancm-multiple-in-process-applications-in-same-process-asp-ne)  that fixed it by deleting **.vs Folder**, On Saturday morning I downloaded the new visual studio update 16.6.0. This morning the application running on the server started showing the same error, without any changes to the it, I followed the same step I used to fix it earlier but still didn't fix it, please is there any other solution to fix this? Because right now everything is working fine in my local machine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since, there won't be any .vs folder when you deploy the app on the server, most probably multiple applications sharing the same app pool might be the cause. The same is described in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553193/1363011)  post that you have mentioned. Didn't it helped you?

Comment: When I deleted the **.vs Folder** and reopened the the solution, the **.vs folder** was recreated, so the deployment wasn't without the **.vs Folder**

Comment: Is your application hosted on IIS? The worker process can't run multiple in-process apps in the same process. To fix this error, run apps in separate IIS application pools.

Comment: Thanks, I just resolved the issue, by first copying the project to a different machine that has my earlier version of visual studio 19, then published from there, the on my machine I deleted the .vs folder and all publish settings, the imported a new publish settings from the hosting company, then tried from my machine, now it's working fine.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Thangadural please is there no permanent solution to this kind of error? It keeps  occurring over and over again... After fixing the last time is has happen again, there must be a way to stop it from happening.

Comment: I got this response from an .NET Core app on IIS and it was that I have forgotten to put the app in it's own app pool. I have not experienced this in IIS Express.