# HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process - Azure App Service dotnet 5

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying 2 different projects in an azure web app service. The service is configured to be running dotnet 5. I am using virtual directory to deploy 3 applications in this app service. The default app, a dotnet 5 app, runs fine. On the first subsites if I deploy a dotnet 2.1 app, that works perfectly. But when I try to deploy a dotnet 5 app on the second subsite it shows the mentioned error in question - added an image of it
[image]

As far as I understood this is probably happening because they share same application pool. I tried the following stuffs:

- Deployed as a self-contained app
- Added **AspNetCoreModuleV2** and **out of process** tags in csproj files of all projects as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246822/http-error-500-35-ancm-multiple-in-process-applications-in-same-process-asp-ne) (and a few more answers from that link)

Frankly speaking I couldnt find much help in the net and not really sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Blazor Server and Web Api (net6.0) in my Application, to deploy I had the same problem that you.

To solve it, I added in both csproj (Blazor and WebApi) this code:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It's allows that the process take separated. After, in web config deploy, you can see the change.