# How to load .gltf in a Blazor application

Tags: three.js, blazor, static-files, gltf

I am trying to load .gltf model using three.js into my Blazor application. 
[image]
However the server does not serve this type of files. 
[image]
I am aware that MIME type must be added, but for some reasons, that cannot be done with Blazor web app as the 'app' variable in Startup.cs is an instance of `IComponentsApplicationBuilder`. Can anybody help me with this issue.

Comment: What's the actual server, is it IIS?  Do you have a `web.config` file?

Comment: IISExpress .. There is no web.config files for Blazor applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIS and IIS Express will not serve files with unknown extensions.  In your error console, you see `404 (Not Found)` which means either the file is missing, or the MIME type for the file is not registered.

I would recommend you try adding a `web.config` file to the root of your application, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".gltf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".gltf" mimeType="model/gltf+json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".glb" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".glb" mimeType="model/gltf-binary" />
            <remove fileExtension=".bin" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".bin" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `<remove ... />` statements are there to avoid any possible conflicts with any MIME type registrations that happen in parent folders or at the root-level or system-level.  It's always safe to `remove`, but it's a configuration error to add one that already exists.

Here's a reference to where the [glTF Mime Type](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/943#issuecomment-342553198) was defined.

Some versions of IIS Express will disregard MIME types from `web.config`.  If this happens, the above file may not work.  In that case you may have to edit the IIS Express configuration file directly, to add the information shown above.  Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946477/836708) to see how to locate that config file.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to mess around with `web.config`.

You just need to inject the `StaticFileOptions` from `Program.cs`.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;


...


builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider
    {
        Mappings =
        {
            [".gltf"] = "model/gltf+json",
            [".glb"] = "model/gltf-binary",
            [".bin"] = "application/octet-stream"
        }
    };
});
```

Full docs with an alternative option:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server-file-mappings-and-static-file-options