# IIS express config paths

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, iis-express-10

Problem statement :- Have one VS (2017) solution with 2 web projects inside it, both using IIS Express 10.0
**Project one** :- using IIS Express config path which is regular IIS config path.

C:\Users\ravi\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

**Project two** Using config path :-
C:\git\3.6.2\Project2\ADMIN.vs\config\applicationhost.config

Question is :-  Want to change config path for project 2 IIS express server. So that both should use same path i.e. which is there in project 1.

Tried so far :- All documentation related to this one but config part is really messy, nothing seems to be working so far.

System configuration

**Visual Studio 2017

IIS express version 10.0**
**Winodws 10**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the IIS Express configuration / metabase file found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946476/where-is-the-iis-express-configuration-metabase-file-found)

Comment: Read "UseGlobalApplicationHostFile" from the linked thread.