# Windows Authentication doesn't work with IIS Express 10 when running Visual Studio 2017 under another account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, windows-authentication, iis-express

Original question here:

[Windows Authentication doesn't work with IIS Express 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789343/windows-authentication-doesnt-work-with-iis-express-10/)

At my workplace, we do development on a production network, meaning we have a regular, restricted account and an "admin" account, which has greater rights.  We recently had a hardware refresh where we went from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and VS 2013 to VS 2017.

Under the old system, I could log in with my regular account, run VS 2013 as my admin account, and I was able to build and run my web application just fine in Firefox.

This does not work under Windows 10.  When I try running VS 2017 under my admin account while logged into my regular account, windows authentication fails, giving me either 401.1 or 401.2 errors.  The only way I have been able to get everything working is to log into my admin account and run it from there.  This isn't the preferred way to do things.  So, is there any way to do what I want to do in Windows 10 and VS 2017?

Comment: Like your previous question showed, the setup your workspace used is rare, and can easily go out of Microsoft's sights when they upgrade their products. Ask your manager and open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com. That's the best way to let them know how this product is used by your team and how the problem affects your usage.

Comment: Part of this is fighting against policy to be able to do my job, but some of this is also backsliding by Microsoft.  I should be able to do the equivalent of sudo in Windows 10, and they seem to have broken it.