# Why is my MVC3 web page not sending Windows credentials to IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I have been struggling with getting Windows Authentication to work with my MVC3 application in development (VS 2010 SP1), with no real luck so far.  I am running XP on my dev machine (no money until next year for an upgrade), if that makes a difference.  I should also mention I am using IIS Express as the default web development server from VS 2010.

I started with an empty MVC3 app awhile back, as I didn't have the Intranet template available from the VS menu until I upgraded the MVC3 tools yesterday (OK, I was a little slow).  Once I installed and inspected that template, I added a reference to DirectoryServices to my project and added the bit of code that displays the current logged-on user in the upper right corner of the page.  According to the graphics, it should now say "Welcome PCE\dnewman!"

I followed the excellent instructions in this post: [IIS Express Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication) and did make some headway.  However, I now get the 401.2 error from IIS Express, telling me I am not authorized...

So, I went in to my project properties and set Anonymous Authentication to Enabled.  Now I can access the web page, but what I see in the upper right corner of my page is "Welcome !" -- no username.

I tried this with both IE and Firefox, with the same result. What the $#^&! am I missing here?  It seems I am not logged in to Windows!! Where do I need to start looking for the problem?

At a previous employer a couple of years back, I wrote a Windows Forms app that authenticated the user with their Windows logon credentials.  In that case, I had to take special care to both send the credentials and then to explicitly authenticate them on the service end. Is there something I have to do to make the browser include credentials with every GET or POST?

By request, here's the contents of my web.config, with apologies for all the Glimpse config stuff.

```
<?xml version="1.0" 
  encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="glimpse" 
         type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.GlimpseConfiguration" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" 
     value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" 
     value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" 
             targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" 
       enabled="true" 
       pageOutput="false" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Glimpse" 
       type="Glimpse.Core.Module" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="glimpse.axd" 
       verb="GET,POST" 
       type="Glimpse.Core.Handler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Glimpse" 
       type="Glimpse.Core.Module,Glimpse.Core" 
       preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Glimpse" 
       path="glimpse.axd" 
       verb="GET,POST" 
       type="Glimpse.Core.Handler,Glimpse.Core" 
       preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IReporting" 
             maxBufferSize="1024000" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" 
                    maxStringContentLength="65536" 
                    maxArrayLength="32768" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="normalBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="tcpAdminServiceEndpoint" 
            address="net.tcp://PCESRV22.pce.local:9000/ProductionMonitor/AdminService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="normalBinding" 
            contract="Contracts.IAdmin" />
      <endpoint name="tcpMasterDataServiceEndpoint" 
            address="net.tcp://PCESRV22.pce.local:9010/ProductionMonitor/MasterDataService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="normalBinding" 
            contract="Contracts.IMasterData" />
      <endpoint name="tcpReportingServiceEndpoint" 
            address="net.tcp://PCESRV22.pce.local:9030/ProductionMonitor/ReportingService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IReporting" 
            contract="Contracts.IReporting" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" 
                      publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" 
                     newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <glimpse enabled="true" />
</configuration>
```

I am more than willing to divulge more details as needed, but I really don't even know where to start looking.  Every post or article I can find seems to assume this part just happens as part of the Windows/MVC3/ASP.NET setup.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Did you disable anonymous authentication as mentioned in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication/7168308#7168308

Comment: I second the disabling of anonymous authentication.  You mention you're using IIS express? What happens if you debug the application?  Put a breakpoint on your constructor and let me know what you find in `this.User.Identity`

Comment: As to the first comment, yes I did.  That is referenced by the same post I referred to above.  When that didn't work I re-Enabled it to see what would happen and got the blank username.  When I debug it with Anonymous enabled and look at this.User.Identity I get what I would expect from my observations, an empty string.  When I disable anonymous authentication the app dies with the 401.2 error before it hits my breakpoint (at Application_Start in Global.asax.cs)

Comment: BTW, I need to have anonymous authentication enabled, as I only wish to secure certain pages in the site.  Most of the site needs to be available to everyone.

Comment: @Dave Do you have   `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in your Web.config?

Comment: Not exactly, as that syntax seems to be invalid.  I do have  <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>  in the <system.webServer><security><authentication> section of my Web.config file, as described in the afore-referenced posting...

Comment: Just for kicks I went back and added <authentication mode="Windows"/> to the <system.web> section of Web.config -- same results.

Comment: @Dave Ok, so first of all, you need to disable the anonymous access.  Having it on will result in the null username.  If it's anonymous, IIS does not read the credentials and therefore doesn't pass it to your application.  Once you disable it, you need to enable "Integrated Windows authentication". It might help if you could post your entire web.config in your original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow all the recommendations in the referenced post, you'll end up with a non-working mess, like I did.  Each answer has its own merit, but applying all of them only ends in frustration.

The post from Microsoft that answered all questions and got me working is here: [How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx)

Save this link, it's golden...

I also found the "Add Deployable Dependencies" option can break Windows authentication.  If I selected the "ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor syntax" option in the "Add Deployable Dependencies" dialog box, it immediately broke Windows authentication and seemed to go back to forms authentication -- I got a 404 error "The resource cannot be found" looking for /Account/Login.  I didn't have to deploy it, just selecting that option broke it.  The only way to fix it then is to start over.  I was unable to remove enough of anything to get it to start working again, and I was unable to determine what change was made that caused this behavior.

This blog post saved the day: [How to Deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 App to Web Hosting with "\bin Deployment"](http://drew-prog.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-deploy-aspnet-mvc-3-app-to-web.html) - it shows which assemblies are needed and how to get them included with your web app when you deploy it WITHOUT using the "Add Deployable Dependencies" nonsense.

I hope this saves somebody the hours I spent trying to get it all to work.

Comment: I just did Add Deployable Dependencies. Went to my deployment and found the 404 error described. Assumed I had done something wrong in setup. Went back to my debug site to notice it too had stopped. Merely by clicking the damn option. I will try what you have suggested. +1

Comment: This post helped me solve my problem. You must manually revert the damage done by "Add Deployable Dependencies" (source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg286946(v=vs.110).aspx). Microsoft provides no instructions on what files you actually need to remove but I got my project running again after removing files from my project folders `bin` and `_bin_deployableAssemblies`. Also be aware content is added to `web.config` `<system.data>` (and perhaps at other places to).

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. In my WebAPI application, I had enabled "Windows Authentication" for IIS express, but did not disable Anonymous Authentication. My User.Identity.Name was empty string until I did the latter.