# Getting the value of Request.ServerVariables(“LOGON_USER”)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, authorization, request.servervariables

I'm trying to get authenticated username in my ASP.NET page using `Request.ServerVariables(“LOGON_USER”)` variable. It gives me an empty string. There are a lot of topics about this variable. [The common point](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359/EN-US) is using an authentication type other than None and denying anonymous access. So I added these lines in my `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users = "?" /> <!-- This denies access to the Anonymous user -->
  <allow users ="*" /> <!-- This allows access to all users -->
</authorization>
```

I still get an empty string. How can I get the username?

Also tried:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"];
Request.ServerVariables["UNMAPPED_REMOTE_USER"];
Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Make sure, you are logged into the website and in authenticated page you are checking this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed. You should **disable anonymous access** in IIS if you want to use `Request.ServerVariables(“LOGON_USER”)`.

PS: Disabling anonymous access has some side effects such as [infinite login redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065466/infinite-redirect-loop-for-basic-or-windows-authentication)

Comment: Check the properties in your web project file.  There are settings for IIS in the project.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743550/iis-express-is-automatically-disabling-anonymous-authentication-for-my-project