# Visual Studio 2012 Debugging MVC 4 Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-8

Has anyone received the following error when trying to debug in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8?  It is a standard (out of the box haven't even changed the styling yet) MVC 4 application running on .Net 4.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access is denied. 
>     Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication/7168308#7168308

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered my own question.  Issue was my setup.  Using an Intranet Template in a non-AD environment.

From web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: that will only disable authentication and make you log in anonimous. If you implement authorization anywhere it wont work. you should check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053666/iis-express-gives-access-denied-error-when-debugging-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Disabling authentication was sufficient for my use case as the final product was going to be inside of a domain and I denied unknown users in the final product.