# Why does System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name return an empty string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code to verify if the user has access to the application or not. Problem is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` returns empty. I checked. What could be the problem? My other application uses the same code snippet and it works there. Why is this happening?

```
string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
string str = "SELECT LASTNAME +', '+ FIRSTNAME AS NAME, USER_NAME, DEPARTMENT FROM DBNAME.DBO.TABLENAME WHERE USER_NAME = '" + username + "' ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
if (rdr.HasRows == false)
{

        Server.Transfer("unauthorized.htm");
}
else
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        name = rdr["NAME"].ToString();
        username = rdr["USER_NAME"].ToString();
        dept = rdr["DEPARTMENT"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code taken from an ASP.net app?

Comment: Do both apps manage their own authentication state?

Comment: maybe worth giving us your web.config

Comment: What authentication you were using? Form, Federation? You need to look at your authentication code, see how the user was populated

Comment: You might want to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8841841/293712 and user other option

Comment: It's not of much use showing us everything _after_ getting the empty string - we kinda need to know how it came to be that way by knowing how you handle log-ins.

Comment: I set `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in the web.config

Comment: @GrantThomas I have this code on page_load of my default page. I don't know what you mean by how I handle log-ins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have an anonymous user.  If you don't want to allow anonymous users, add the following to web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This just gives me Server Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: Is IIS configured to use Windows authentication and do you have `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in the web.config?

Comment: Yes and Yes. This is just weird. My other application has the same code. And it works fine there.

Comment: Uh oh! So I was stupid and I really did forget to configure the IIS Authentication. I just thought I already did it but not.

Comment: And what configuration did you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows authetication with IIS Express, make sure you have  in C:\Users\[username]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config .

Check related question: [IIS Express gives Access Denied error when debugging ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053666/iis-express-gives-access-denied-error-when-debugging-asp-net-mvc)