# Web api windows authorization denied

Tags: c#, .net

I want windows authentication in my web api, but I always get the following message: "Authorization has been denied for this request." Am I missing something?

IIS settings:

[image]

Web config:

[image]

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/testauthentication")]
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult TestAutentication()
{
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution over here:

[IIS Express gives Access Denied error when debugging ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053666/iis-express-gives-access-denied-error-when-debugging-asp-net-mvc)

[image]