# asp.net mvc 5 CSS loads on localhost not on remote machine

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I've created a asp.net mvc 5 app project (no app so far) when I go to http://localhost:12345/ it shows the asp.net default index page:
[image]

But if I go to http://development_machine_ip:12345/ from a remote machine it shows the unstyled page:
[image]

Note I am using Windows Authentication on an Intranet app. I am using the same credentials in both machines.

This issue is present in Firefox, Chrome an IE. The site is not being displayed in intranet compatibilitymode as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/142721/iis-displaying-page-differently-when-localhost-is-used-in-url-vs-hostname)

I've also set project folder permission to read and execute for all domain users  and added the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10.0" />` tag without success.

I am using IIS Express and Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks for considering my question.

**SOLUTION:**

> the clue is to give the appropriate permissions to IIS_IUSRS. But until that it's easier to launch VS 2010 with administrator privilages.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060303/when-using-iis-express-no-css-applied-on-a-remote-pc) link provided in this question comments by @barry

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060303/when-using-iis-express-no-css-applied-on-a-remote-pc

Comment: @barry My problem was not the same but it helped me to notice why it happened. If you post it as an answer I'll selected it as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, That is not my answer so can't post it here.