# WebApp MVC5 on windows server 2016 and IIS 10 without loading css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, iis

i have published my webapp mvc5 on IIS 10 with windows server 2016.

Now it shows my WebApp with out loading css.

I Turn on all the features under Common HTTP Features and still does not work any idea?
Thanks..

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: if view source is the css file present?

Comment: it does not shows error only my WebApp not loading css

Comment: @Animus Miles . there is source view but all the design look messy and different

Comment: Does this happen with all browsers?  Does it occur on both localhost & remote connections?  Can you include a screen shot?  Here's a similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060303/when-using-iis-express-no-css-applied-on-a-remote-pc

Comment: i have solved the problem deleted all the bootstrap.min.css in my Content thanks alot

Comment: This doesn't sound like a solution at all.