# MVC app with windows authentication with Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have been reading a few post here about to remove Negotiate and try other stuff.  But I think my problem is different in that Chrome doesn't even attempt to prompt me for a username or password but automatically tries to send me to a login.aspx page which does not exist.

Current Web Config Settings are

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
  <identity impersonate="true" />
```

IIS 7.5 Express Settings has anonymous disabled and Windows authentication enabled

NTLM is the only provider
Extended protection is Off
Enable Kernel-mode authentication checked

Any ideas?

IE is working fine, as expected.

I am trying to learn MVC so I have been working on the MVC Store project.
If I use the local VisualStudio Development Server Chrome works fine.  So it must be something with IIS 7.5 Express

Comment: have you seen this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2011/08/02/iis-7-401.2-error.aspx) for a solution to similar problem. Hope this will help you.
In case if this won't help can you give more details about the problem? You check event log for errors and requests in debugger tool like chrome extension(F12) for more information.