# 401.2 when accessing localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on windows 10.
After enabling IIS10 (with .NET 4.6) when I access localhost in browser I get

> Server Error in '/' Application.

Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.79.0

Anonymous Authentication is enabled and rest disabled. If I go to Programs and Features and un-checking 4.6 localhost is accessible. What is the problem with 4.6?

Comment: I'm getting this same issue too, never had this problem with windows 8 so not sure what's missing in the default win 10 / .net install

Comment: I know this is really old, but check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857049/259725) it got it working for me