# How can I access an ASP.NET MVC application through IIS Express while using OpenCover?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express, opencover

I am using OpenCover to cover a very simple ASP.NET MVC application. It's basically just a shell application: a handful of controller methods and not much else.

I am attempting to user OpenCover to launch an instance of IIS 8.0 Express, through which I will run the MVC application. However, when I try to browse to the site, I get an "Access is denied" 401.2 error. I have tried numerous things to solve this, mostly revolving around different ways to enable Windows Authentication. Most of my attempts have been based on advice from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication/7168308). Despite my efforts, I'm still getting this 401.2 error. Also, I should point out that when running this application through VS2013, I can access the site just fine.

One final detail is that in order to use OpenCover, I cannot use the full version of IIS because OpenCover and IIS don't work well together, so IIS Express is a must. If there is any sort of configuration details I can provide you with in order for you to better help me, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: How are you running OpenCover to run iisexpress? NOTE: OpenCover was really designed with unit testing in mind so perhaps there is something wrong with how you are trying to execute iisexpress as compared to nunit-console and the like.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that it ended up coming down to how I had iisexpress configured. In the end, I ended up using OpenCover to launch Visual Studio and run the project that way. Doing that, I was able to get the coverage we were looking for. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Eek, I hope you eventually find a better solution :)