# httpContext.User.Identity.Name Coming back as " "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext

I am trying to get a username from my windows authenticated MVC 5 Application but the string keeps coming back as "" or empty. I can get the username fine in my controller but when using this new class i cannot retrieve it.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using EmployeeMaster.CustomAttribute;


namespace EmployeeMaster.CustomAttribute
{
    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1).ToUpper();
            return GetUserSecurityLevel(username);
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (!AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                // If not authorized, redirect to the NotAuthorizedForApplication action 
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
                   {"action", "NotAuthorizedForApplication"}
                }
                );
            }
        }

        private bool GetUserSecurityLevel(string username)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my web config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MailServer" value="mail2.pacificdda.com" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
      <remove name="Session"/>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
      <remove name="BundleModule"/>
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
     </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have seen posts similar to mine but I have tried the common things and cannot get them to work on both localhost and server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your authorization element in your config file.

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

That is telling your site to allow anonymous users.  It should be:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

The site will stop at the first one to evaluate as true, so if the user is anonymous they will be denied access, otherwise they will be allowed.

EDIT

Authentication works by first sending a 401 to the browser which specifies the type of authentication.  That prompts the browser to ask for credentials.  The authorization node in your web.config OR the authorization attributes on your controller are what prompt this to happen.  If your web.config is set to allow anonymous users, then there is no 401. If there is no 401, no credentials will be sent, and Identity.Name will be empty.

It probably works in your controller because you included the AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: I got a 401.2 access denied

Comment: You also have to enable Windows Auth in IIS Express, and potentially comment out some code.  See the following post for enabling Windows Authentication:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication

The code is the app.UseCookieAuthentication in Startup.Auth.cs