# How to configure IIS Express properly so that it would allow anonymous login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm converting my current MVC application which uses windows based authentication to forms based. I have made changes in web.config and `global.asax` file. Now when I run the application, it goes to login page and with the user's credentials validated, its gets navigated to other page. My issue is when I do a signout, my `applicationhost.config` file gets rewrited from

```
 <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
```

to

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
```

and then if I hit the home page of my application, it takes my windows credentials.

In my web config I do have

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Logon/Index"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

In global.asax I have

```
 string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
 string roles = string.Empty;
 //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
 HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                          new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
 ISecurityUserIdentity objUser = null;
 objUser = SecurityLibrary.Security.GetUser(username, Mgr.GetSecurityAttribute());
 Context.User = objUser;
```

My issue is why my `applicationhost.config` file rewrites automatically when I do a signout and change my authentication mode.

Comment: How about [this][1] method for IIS8 Express?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication

Comment: Yes I resolved my problem using the following steps. select the web project and press F4 to focus the Properties panel.
Set the "Windows Authentication" property to disabled, and the "Anonymous Authentication" property to enabled. Thanks EkzoMan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS Express Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication)