# Windows authentication on webpage - No user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have enabled Windows Authentication in my webconfig. Now I want to retrieve the user who Is trying to access the webpage like this:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {

            var username2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

I can't get any user from the `Curent.User.Identity.Name`. It's just blank. Why this?

I have also tried to disable Anonymous Authentication, but when I do this, a login dialog Is prompted. I don't want that.

I just want to get the computer user who trying to access the page. Is this possible?

And I'm not looking for `Environment.Username`, because that don't work when I deploy to the main server.

Comment: What is hosting environment? IIS/IIS Express?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: So this Is not possible to do? How can I retrive the information the user enter into the login dialog when I have disabled Anonymous Authentication?

Comment: @WueF: On my local machine, It's IIS Express. When I deploy, It's on a regular IIS-server

Comment: Have you enabled windows authentication in IIS express config?

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946304/using-windows-authentication-in-asp-net

Comment: If you're trying to get a local Windows user from a remote connection this way, there are security reasons that's not going to work. That takes wiring up to Active Directory and such.  If I log into Windows as user CDove, the best you're going to do from a website without specific permissions or a directory hookup is get my IP.

Comment: @WueF: Yes I have tried all that.

Comment: @CDove: So this Is not possible?

Comment: Give up `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, and stick to `User` property of your controller. Besides, a prompt is so common for Windows authentication. To suppress the prompt, search on Stack Overflow to learn how to.

Comment: It's not fully clear, are you talking about users from the open internet, not from your internal network? If so you can't do it - for a start, there's nothing to say they're even 
 definitely using Windows, and if they are, they're not part of your Active Directory, so you can't check them (that's what Windows Auth does - it quietly checks your local ActiveDirectory for the user's identity).

Comment: @ADyson: In this case, It's on the internal network because you must have VPN to access It. Is this possible to omit the prompt?

Comment: If you just mean the internal network, then it should work if you enable Windows Auth and turn off Anonymous Access (in IIS and in web.config). Note that only Chrome and IE send the correct Kerberos token automatically. In Firefox it's not connected to the relevant Windows APIs and so the user will have to type their Windows username and password instead. It's also pretty flakey if you use RunAs or anything like that to open your browser. And it only works if the client machine using the VPN is a Windows machine which is joined to the same ActiveDirectory domain as the webserver.

Comment: @Bryan: Correct.  It would be a security problem if I could, say, capture the Windows login of every person from a specific organization who accessed  my website.  It would be a social engineering hacker's dream.  On top of that, what would happen if the user logged in from Linux or a Mac?  You can only scrape usernames for Windows using Windows Auth on an intranet without consent of a directory, and that is by design.

Comment: @ADyson: I have enabled Windows ath and turned off Anonymous Access, but It still prompts.

Comment: What about the other comments I made? Did you verify your client PC / browser meets all the necessary conditions?

Comment: @ADyson: Going to check this now.

Comment: A sensible thing would be to check and compare using a machine which is connected directly to the domain's LAN and not via VPN. Then we can rule that in or out as a factor.

Comment: @ADyson: You where right about chrome. The prompts is not shown in chrome, but it is shown in firefox.

Comment: yes, that's simply because Firefox doesn't plug in to the right Windows APIs to get the security token automatically, for whatever reason. It's well known that this is the case. There is an extension for Firefox available which provides this.

Answer (score -1):

Pls try using [Authorize] attribute

My code in the Controller works like so -

```
    [Authorize(Roles="# Some_team_name")]
    public ActionResult Foo(string param1)
    {
        string windowsLogonName = User.Identity.Name;
        ...............
        ...............
```

P.S: I hope the moderators would appreciate that to comment one still needs 50 points, so I am putting my comments in the answer block. Hope that is ok.

Comment: You better remove `P.S.` before it's too late. You are attempting to answer, so it may be ok to post as an answer. If your answer is bad - you will get downvotes, but saying "Hey, you have rules and I am going to break them" is so wrong ;)