# Windows Authentication for IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4, windows-authentication

I'm having an issue where my client prompts for windows username/password when trying to use windows auth with IdentityServer4. I have tried following documentation, but it hasn't worked out for me at this point.

I'm using IIS Express for both projects.

I have two projects:

> Server: Can login using Windows, and see all claims.

> Client: Simple MVC app that redirects to Server, then returns to display claims.

When logging in with Windows on the server project, everything works well.
When I login on the client, I am always prompted for a Username/Password prompt for windows.  Which is not ideal.

Something I've noticed, on the server, in `launchSettings.json` if I set  `"anonymousAuthentication": true` the client always prompts for the credentials.  If I set `"anonymousAuthentication": false`, the client almost seems work, but I get a 402 error on the .wellknown endpoints.

Comment: could  this be applicable to your case?: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004028/898142

Comment: I don't think so, since it appears to be working barring the requirement to re-enter credentials.

Answer (score 0):

So I realize what was happening now.  I was running my 'client' in an incognito chrome window.  I'm not sure why this is the case, but chrome was not performing the Windows challenge automatically while in incognito.  Using a regular chrome tab fixed the issue immediately.