# Where to find Use IIS Express option while using Windows Authentication in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am trying to implement windows authentication in one of my MVC projects. I am referring this article for the same [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx) but the problem i am facing is , in this article on the first step they ask us to select an option which is shown in the image[image]

but i am not able to find this option, when i right click i get this options
[image]

can anyone help me on how and where i could find this option.
I am also not able to find the second option, in the msdn link it shows an option like this
[image]

Thank you

but in my local solution i dont see the mentioned option, my local solution options are as this[image]

Resolve:

[image]

Comment: Please try this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/7168308

Comment: @AkınAbdullahoğlu thanks, do you know the solution for my second update as well

Comment: Left Click Your Web Application and look right lower Windows Authentication Property set Enabled.

Comment: Please check this link. http://pasteboard.co/hgiMpQOb1.png

Comment: @AkınAbdullahoğlu thanks :)

Comment: @AkınAbdullahoğlu i am just curious about the other image, that is where can i find the NTLM Authentication option if i want to opt for an NTLM authentication. could you please help me on that as well
Thanks for your help:)